# Unit test in dojo

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dojo, jasmine, doh

I'm starting with dojo. Coming from GWT and Backbone, I've worked with junit and jasmine to test my application. After taking a lock on dojo DOH testing framework, I wonder if its worth to use it or would it be better to stay with jan external testing framework like jasmine or busterjs. One of my concerns is that I've not found any source on how to use it with an CI server like jenkins. Also I like to know, if I can use a mocking framwork like sinon with DOH. DOH seems also to lack some convenience matcher like the one in jasmin.

Comment: Did you try doh.robot ? http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/util/dohrobot.html.

Comment: doh.robot is more for ui tests, not for unit test the application logic. As far as I understand the docs, its more like selenium. Also I cant see how it will work with Jenkins.

Comment: I have experience with DOH and my one big complaint is that it's very difficult to debug from it.  They use javascript eval I think to define all your functions so it's difficult to find your code to set a break point.

Answer (score 2):

You may look into this:
http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2012/04/dojo-mocking-dependencies-with-doh.html

I believe that with Doh and Doh robot, you may do a lot. Currently experiencing. Will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are some more you might want to check apart from DOH (which works very well).
You can check eventd and selenium 2 also.
I remember seeing an integration tutorial for Jenkins / selenium 2 haven't tested it though.
EDIT: Maybe needs some refresh, but here you might find more infos : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin

Comment: Sure I can run Selenium with Jenkins but what I'm looking for is a way where I can run DOH tests from Jenkins which inform them if they fail.

Comment: do you mean like a button on jenkins page to run test and report failures ? or more like doing builds running the tests, and reading xml reports ?

Comment: Running test and reading result xml, yes thats what I'm looking for.